# Set Value of Form Input using jQuery AJAX via PHP based on other Input Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form which has 4 inputs, in a table row.

I use Javascript to Add Dynamic Rows to the form: **product,material,variation,charges**

I want to populate value of **charges** using value retrieved from PHP MySQL Database, once I change the value of **product** (select box)

My Current code allows me to do that for the primary row only.

I want this to work independently for all dynamically added rows too and specifically for inputs like -

```
view_material_detail(this.value); →  Displays Image within **<p style=" margin:0 auto;" id="view_material"></p>**

get_Charges(this.value);  → Populates value of 'making_charges' from MySQL Database via AJAX Call .
```

HTML Code (**NewOrder.php**)

```
<form id="newOrder" method="POST">
<div class="">
    <h2 class="PageHeader">New Order</h2>
    <div class="cx_section">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="nope" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="small_input" placeholder="Mobile Number" onKeyup="get_cx_details(this.value);" autofocus="yes">

    <div class="" id="get_cx_details" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">

//Function **get_cx_details** ↑ WORKS FINE

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <table class="Box" width="100%"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="ProductHeader">
        <h2 class="PageHeader">Item</h2></tr>
        </table>

    <div class="item_section" >
        <table class="Box" width="100%"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="OrderTable">

            <tr  id="row1" style="width:100%;">
              <td class="product_row">
              <?php


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `product` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `name` ASC");
echo '
```

Original Code for Dropdown **product**

```
<select onChange="get_Charges(this.value);" name="product[]" id="product">
<option value="">Select Item</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['model'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select></td>';
mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

Code advised by @mplungjan

```
<select name="product[]" class="product">
    <option value="">Select Item</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['model'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select></td>';
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    ?>
```

Code Continues...

```
<td class="product_row"><input id="material" onkeyup="view_material_detail(this.value);" name="material[]"  type="text" placeholder="Material Code" />
<p style=" margin:0 auto;" id="view_material"></p>    
<td class="product_row"><input id="variations" name="variations[]" type="text" placeholder="Variations" /></td>
```

**Making Charges** Value should auto-populate when the value of **Product** changes

Original Code for text input **Making Charges**

```
<td class="product_row" id="making_charges"><input id="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Code advised by @mplungjan -

```
<td class="product_row"><input class="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" /></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Code Continues....

```
    </div>
</div>

<p>
            <input type="button" value="Add Item" onClick="addRow('OrderTable')" class="Box" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete Item" onClick="deleteRow('OrderTable')" class="Box">
          </p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I need the PHP Code for **get_making_charges.php** AJAX Function as well as code to update the value of **making_charges *independently*** (for dynamic inputs also, if any) retrieved from the PHP AJAX Call →

AJAX Function

Original Code for function **get_Charges();**

```
function view_material_detail(val) {  
           $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#mkg_charges").val(data);
    }
    }); 

 }
```

Result → First Row's **Making Charges** changes

Code advised by @mplungjan

```
    $("#OrderTable").on("change",".product",function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+$this.val(),
    success: function(data){
      $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").val(data); // a number? +data to make numeric 
    }
  }); 
});
```

Result Nothing Happens

PHP Script

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
//Include database connection
include __DIR__ . '/../dbconn.php';

if(isset($_POST['product']))  
 // echo $_POST['material'];
    $product_model = trim($_POST["product"]); //escape string
 { 
     $check_existing = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `making_charges` FROM `product` WHERE `model` = '$product_model'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_existing) == 1)
    {
        $result_check = mysqli_fetch_array($check_existing);

$making_charges = $result_check['making_charges'];
 echo $making_charges;

// echo "<input class='mkg_charges' name='making_charges[]' type='number' pattern='[0-9]*' value='$making_charges' />"; 

}


else
    {
       // Nothing Happens
    }

}

?>
```

[image: Screenshot of Form]

As per the screenshot, if I change the value of the first input **Drop Down** box **in the primary row**, nothing happens. Whereas, theoretically the Making Charges should auto-populate. I'm stuck what to choose and how to make this work!

Comment: Use a class. You now have duplicate IDs

Comment: Could you explain by showing me some code for the same , as to highlight where am I going wrong.

Comment: Ok, I've tried some bit of your knowledge but there is an issue. Now that I am getting values in the dynamically added `mkg_charges` field, but for example if I update select box of the 3rd row, the value of 'mkg_charges' gets updated for all the rows.

Comment: Please see my UPDATED answer. You have duplicate IDs on both select and input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resolved finally

@mplungjan

Your code was almost perfect, but you forgot to add a bit of code

**$(document).ready(function(){**

```
$("#OrderTable").on("change",".product",function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+$this.val(),
    success: function(data){
      $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").val(data); // a number? +data to make numeric 
    }
  }); 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jQuery to assign event handlers instead of having in inline. - Remove `onChange="get_Charges(this.value);"` and add the onchange to the script block
2. Use delegation on dynamic elements
3. do not have duplicate IDs. Change `<input id="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]"` to `<input class="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]"`
4. change the select's  `id="product"` to `class="product"`
5. have the PHP `echo $making_charges;` and set the value to that

---

```
$("#OrderTable").on("change",".product",function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+$this.val(),
    success: function(data){
      $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").val(data); // a number? +data to make numeric 
    }
  }); 
});
```

```js
$("#OrderTable").on("change", ".product", function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  var sel = $this.get(0).selectedIndex; // for demonstration
  console.log(sel)
  /* 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data: 'product=' + $this.val(),
    success: function(data) {
      $this.closest("tr").find(".making_charges").html(data);
    }
  });
  */
    $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").val(sel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="newOrder" method="POST">
  <div class="">
    <h2 class="PageHeader">New Order</h2>
    <div class="cx_section">
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" autocomplete="nope" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="small_input" placeholder="Mobile Number" onKeyup="get_cx_details(this.value);" autofocus="yes">

      <div class="" id="get_cx_details" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <table class="Box" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="ProductHeader">
        <h2 class="PageHeader">Item</h2>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <div class="item_section">
        <table class="Box" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="OrderTable">

          <tr id="row1" style="width:100%;">
            <td class="product_row">
              <select name="product[]" class="product">
<option value="">Select Item</option>
    <option value="row1">Row1</option>
    <option value="row2">Row2</option>
</select></td>

            <td class="product_row"><input id="material" onkeyup="view_material_detail(this.value);" name="material[]" type="text" placeholder="Material Code" />
              <p style=" margin:0 auto;" id="view_material"></p>


              <td class="product_row"><input id="variations" name="variations[]" type="text" placeholder="Variations" /></td>

              <td class="product_row"><input class="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>


      </div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Add Item" onClick="addRow('OrderTable')" class="Box" />
      <input type="submit" value="Delete Item" onClick="deleteRow('OrderTable')" class="Box">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Updated Code as per your words - 
              <td class="product_row">
              <?php

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `product` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `name` ASC");
echo '
<select onChange="get_Charges(this.value);" name="product[]" class="product">
<option value="">Select Item</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['model'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select></td>';
mysqli_free_result($result);

?>

Comment: $("#OrderTable").on("change",".product",function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+$this.val(),
    success: function(data){
      $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").html(data);
    }
  }); 
});

Comment: Still doesn't work! It started working as I said before, but not independently. One for all and all for one!

Comment: Please see my changes. Your number field needs .val() and not .html - Do not update the cell, just update the val of the number

Comment: **AJAX** 
`$("#OrderTable").on("change",".product",function() { // delegated on change
  $this = $(this); // save the select for later
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/get_making_charges.php",
    data:'product='+$this.val(),
    success: function(data){
      $this.closest("tr").find(".mkg_charges").val(data); // a number? +data to make numeric 
    }
  }); 
}); `
**id→class**

`<select  name="product[]" class="product">`
**Copied**
`<td class="product_row"><input class="mkg_charges" name="making_charges[]" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" /></td>`

Comment: Why are you posting unformatted code comments. What am I to look at?

Comment: Sorry, I just did it in a hurry!

Comment: So what does the comment mean?

Comment: I've posted updates as to what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the purpose of the comments. You do need to change the php to just return the number contained in $making_charges. Any console errors?

Comment: My primary post was to ask about the php code itself. I am not able to work in the php as per the requirement of the AJAX call. I need your help on that. Have you tried on your local server?

Comment: Of course not. I am not going to spend time adding your code to my server. You do NOT need to return HTML from your server just to set a value. Just return the value and use JavaScript to update the existing input field's value

Comment: Please implement all 5 points I made and you will have a much simpler script and PHP

Comment: I've tried implementing all the code as you have shared, it does not work. No Console Errors! Infact, it is not working at all

Comment: Php errors? There should be some error somewhere - I cannot debug code I cannot run. Have a look in the network console to see if you load the php and it returns a proper value

Comment: I’m on my phone so not now :/